# Firefox hangs after opening Karma Server URL in Docker

Tags: javascript, firefox, docker, karma-runner

**Context**
I have always been running my Karma tests locally in PhantomJS, Google Chrome and Firefox without any problems. Currently, I'm looking to run the Karma tests in Docker and have been having problems with running the Karma tests in Firefox inside a Docker container although the Docker container can run the Karma tests in Google Chrome without any problems.

**Problem**
When I created a Docker container that contains Google Chrome, Firefox, JS libraries (node, npm, grunt ... etc), and VNC utilities (Xvfb, x11vnc). I started the VNC server and ran the tests. Firefox was started and the socket was created with a unique ID. When I entered a VNC session, I could see that firefox was started, the URL was loaded to the URL bar, and the Karma page was loaded. However, after about 2 seconds, the webpage would freeze and the Firefox is hanged. Therefore I could not see `LOG: 'INFO[2015-10-16 20:19:15]: Router Started'` message as well.

**Interesting Find while Reproducing this Manually**
I've tired commenting [the lines that starts Firefox](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-firefox-launcher/blob/master/index.js#L90-L94), so that will only start the karma server when I run the Karma tests. I then tried to run the tests with the following 2 methods -

1. Start a Bash session through `docker exec -it <container_tag>`, execute `firefox`, and typed the server url with the corresponding ID of the test run. Firefox didn't hang in this case and proceeded to start the test run.
2. Start a Bash session through `docker exec -it <container_tag>`, execute `firefox <server_url_with_coresponding_id>`. Firefox didn't hang in this case and proceeded to start the test run.

**My DockerFile**
    FROM ubuntu:14.04

```
#========================
# Environment Variables for Configuration
#========================
ENV GEOMETRY 1920x1080x24
ENV DISPLAY :0

#========================
# Install Required Packages
#========================
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qqy wget \
  wget \
  firefox \
  xvfb \
  x11vnc \
  nodejs \
  npm

#========================
# Install Google Chrome (Latest Stable Version)
#========================
RUN \
  wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
  echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
  apt-get update -qq && \
  apt-get install -qqy google-chrome-stable

#========================
# Clean up Apt
#========================
RUN \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

#========================
# Setup VNC Server
#========================
RUN \
  mkdir -p ~/.vnc && \
  x11vnc -storepasswd 1234 ~/.vnc/passwd

#========================
# Symlink NodeJS
#========================
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

#========================
# Install Grunt and Grunt-CLI
#========================
RUN \
  npm install -g grunt && \
  npm install -g grunt-cli

#========================
# Setup Entry Point
#========================
COPY entry_point.sh /opt/bin/entry_point.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/bin/entry_point.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/bin/entry_point.sh"]
```

I believe that this is a problem relating to the karma-firefox-launcher or karma main library. If anyone can give me some pointers and ideas, that would be great!

Comment: You lack something  installed in your docker container, how to find it is another question

Comment: I have posted my DockerFile. Can you take a look to see if I've missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

I have already submitted PR to karma-firefox-launcher https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-firefox-launcher/pull/45.

This is just for others which might have fall into this.

Firefox has issue with having profile folder on VirtualBox shared folders see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=801274 which is used with Docker setup. Trick is to specify profile folder outside of shared folder like so:

in karma.conf.js:

```
browsers: [ 'FirefoxDocker' ],
browserNoActivityTimeout: 30000, // < might be necessary for slow machines
customLaunchers: {
  FirefoxDocker: {
    base: 'Firefox',
    profile: '/tmp/firefox' // < location is up to you but make sure folder exists
  }
},
```

**Remember to update to version v0.1.7 to make this work.**